# Add Home Folder Hard Drive to Favorites and Desktop

Tags: macos, partition, desktop, sidebar

I just reinstalled my Mac, thinking I'd give OS X Mountain Lion a try.

In my system, I have both a regular HDD with a partition `Storage` and a SSD. On the SSD, I've installed OS X, and now transfered `/Users/kba` (my home folder) to `/Volumes/Storage`, so that the `Storage` partition now *is* my home folder. For the most part, this works great.

However, after having done this, OS X now no longer recognizes `Storage` as a partition — it won't allow it to show up on my Desktop next to my SSD `Macintosh HD`. It no longer shows under *Devices* in the Finder sidebar either.

But worst of all, I can't seem to add it to the sidebar! When I go to `/Users` and drag `kba` to Favorites, it only stays there for a fraction of a second. Same thing happens if I check `Storage` (Home folder) in the Finder Preferences: `Storage` blinks, then disappears from the sidebar and takes the ✔ in the checkbox along as it goes.

#### *mount* output

```
/dev/disk0s1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s2 on /Volumes/Storage (hfs, local, journaled)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
```

#### *ls -h@lde /Volumes/Storage* output

```
drwxrwxr-x@ 32 kba  staff   1,1K 30 Jul 20:26 /Volumes/Storage
com.apple.FinderInfo      32B
```

Comment: How is "Storage" mounted ? Sounds like it might be mounted with the "nobrowse" option. Could you add the output of the "mount" command to your question ?

Comment: No problem here with sidebar presentation of my Core Storage encrypted ZFS home on 10.8.

Comment: @Tyr, I don't know what _nobrowse_ is, but I can easily browse the hard drive by clicking _Music_ (e.g.) in the sidebar and then choose _Storage_ in the Path Bar. Also, I've added `mount` output.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin Is your disk the `/Users` folder or just your private home folder (`/Users/graham`)? Does the disk show up in _Devices_ in the sidebar?

Comment: Home for me (gjp22) is `/Volumes/gjp22` and yes, it's a device in the sidebar. If you log in as a different user, can that user see your `Storage` as a device in the sidebar? Please add to the question the result of ls `-h@lde /Volumes/Storage`

Comment: I don't have other users, but prior to changing my home directory to `/Volumes/Storage`, I had no trouble seeing _Storage_ in the sidebar.

Comment: Is your homedir set to /Volumes/Storage directly or did you put a link in /Users/kba pointing there ?

Comment: @Tyr I set my homedir from _System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> kba -> Advanced Options_. This automatically creates a symlink: _`/Users/kba` -> `/Volumes/Storage/`_.

Comment: That link isn't automatically created afaik. I'm with Graham, create a second user that way you can test an umount/mount via Disk Utility and see what happens. You need a second user anyway be able to login to your machine in case the Storage disk fails.

Comment: Yes, the link is in fact created automatically. I'll create a new test account now, then.

Comment: Yes, the link is in fact created automatically. Storage does not show up in Devices when logged in to another account, but I can, however, still access it through Terminal. I suspect it's because it's owned by `kba`, but I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I've solved it myself.** I just tried to drag `Storage` into Favorites now and it works for some reason!

I'm thinking that it's because I (a few days ago) wrote found a command that was meant to remove `nobrowse`. (I don't recall exactly where I found it or exactly what it was, so I can't paste it here. Sorry).

After running the command, `Storage` suddenly appeared on my Desktop, even though (as it can also be see in the question) OS X didn't mention anything about the drive having the flag `nobrowse`. Either way, after `Storage` appeared on the Desktop, I still couldn't make it show up under Favorites. Until now. I hadn't tried to reboot earlier, so that might be why it suddenly works.

Thanks to everyone trying to help in the comments above.

Comment: I'm glad the issue is worked around. If it recurs:  somewhere in one of the stacks, I recall a question or answer about the `.plist` that is, or was, used for sidebar stuff (keywords: *Network* and *Shared*). From what you describe, it's possible that the preference file was corrupt … maybe an edge case involving an upgrade or migration from Lion.